# How to decompress a huffman encoded file?

Tags: c++, huffman-code

So once I have built my huffman tree and compressed a file into each characters' corresponding code how do I go about decompressing the file? In the compressed file I have to insert some sort of information representing the huffman tree built in order to decompress the file. I was initially thinking of storing the character with its' value for example:

a: 110 and b:11 for example. However, when reading the compressed file how would I differentiate the a from the b if both the a and b start with 11?

I don't feel like my method will work, does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding about huffman encoding. Any character code in Huffman encoded code table must not be a prefix of other characters. If 'a' in your code is 110, 'b' must never starts with 1, 11 or 110. Each of character must not share their prefix.

Comment: Thank you! This makes much more sense. So when reading from let's say from a file, would I read it character by character then?

Comment: Mike, size of each code in Huffman tabels is variable. Actually that's how huffman tree reduces it's size compared to fixed length character like ASCII. You can read data byte by byte, but you should handle it bit by bit. Suppose you read a byte of data, 01011110, and there're two characters whose codes are 010 and 11. Then you can decode it using bit operation and figure out that there're 010, 11, 11 and 0 remains, which should be processed in the next byte.